# Is my residual scatter-plot normal? can I still run a linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model, linear

Am I still able to run a regression if my residuals look like these?
This has happened to all my variables: it's equally distributed but very systematic. Is there a way i can fix this? My p-p plots look normal.

[image]

[image]

My p-p plots look like this for most of my variables. 
[image]

Comment: It's not possible to determine any distributions from these plots because the discrete, regular nature of the data suggests there may be extensive over-plotting of points: you need to use some technique to resolve that ambiguity, such as jittering the points.

Comment: Are your variables truly continuous, or do they take only specific discrete values? Also, what do the two plots represent?

Comment: i have 800 participants in my study, running a series of regression, one continuous IV (pain severity) and one continuous DV (quality of life).

Comment: @whuber i've added my p-p plots, is that what you mean by over-plotting of the points? what techniques can i use to fix this?

Comment: If there is only one IV, how are you running a series of regressions? Are you sure your variables are continuous? Most measures of pain severity and QOL are ordinal.

Comment: Note that the residuals fall on five lines in your first plot. That's because residual = observed response $-$ fitted response and as there are (evidently!) just 5 distinct values of the response there are 5 lines all with the same slope. As @PeterFlom implied, many statistical people would prefer something like an ordinal logit here.

Comment: Yes, sorry it's ordinal, it's a likert scale. I meant for each regression that i'm running, there's one iv and one dv.

Comment: There are evidently just 11 distinct values of your predictor (you say "dv"), so just 11 distinct values predicted too. The grid pattern of your first two plots is just a side-effect of the granularity of your two variables.

Comment: The original scatter plot of response versus predictor would make things clearer to you. Find out about "jittering" in your software. If your software doesn't support jittering, you need better software.

Comment: In my experience quantile (Q-Q) plots are more informative than P-P plots.

Comment: my q-q plots showed normal data distribution, i only found issues with my residuals, i want to make the residual homoscedastic, so basically i should just apply jittering to my residual plots?

Comment: I  have to say that you seem way out of your depth here and don't understand well  many basic ideas. Depending on your situation, you may need to seek more help from an advisor, supervisor, or mentor. Getting residuals homoscedastic is a secondary issue. The main question is whether your regression makes sense at all. Jittering is just a way to show data and results more intelligibly and can't improve anything -- nor will it make matters worse.

Comment: Quality of life can hardly be called continuous with just 11 observed levels. Nor does it make any sense to call a distribution of 5 discrete values "normal".

Comment: sorry, i'm not good at stats, i just wanted to know how i can fix my residuals to allow me to perform a regression

Comment: You've performed it already. As already said, the first issue is whether it makes sense. The behaviour of residuals is secondary. Superimposing a regression line on a scatter plot with jittered data points would be a good first step.  Your data reduce to 51 pairs of predictor and response values so you should be able to show those pairs and their frequencies compactly to give people a concrete idea of what you have. I can only guess at your software (SPSS???) so can't advise on how to do that precisely.